# Python: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not string

Tags: python

Guys i have just started learning Python.. I have no deep idea about it. I stuck in this List and Dictionaries related problem.. it shows me an error message. 
The Error O/P and the codes are given below..

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 48, in <module>
  File "python", line 45, in get_class_average
  File "python", line 25, in get_average
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not st




lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}


def average(numbers):
    total = float(sum(numbers))/len(numbers)
    return total

def get_average(student):
    homework = average(student['homework'])
    quizzes = average(student['quizzes'])
    tests = average(student['tests'])
    return 0.1*homework + \
    0.3*quizzes + \
    0.6*tests

def get_letter_grade(score):
    if score>=90:
        return "A"
    elif score>=80:
        return "B"
    elif score>=70:
        return "C"
    elif score>=60:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"

get_letter_grade(get_average(lloyd))

def get_class_average(students):
    results=[];
    results.append(get_average(students));
    return average(results)

sts=[lloyd,alice,tyler];
get_class_average(sts)
```

Comment: You're passing `students`, a list, to `get_average`, then you try to index it using `'homework'`, a string.

Comment: `l.append(f(x))` doesn't apply `f` to all elements of list `x` and save all the results as new elements in `l`. Please review the documentation for lists.

Comment: Ya i got it bro.. It was just a silly mistake by me.. You know as m beginner in Python. Btw thnx bro for u kind help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `students` variable is a list with three students (erm... three *dictionaries*).

When you do `results.append(get_average(students));`, you're passing that list to your `get_average` method, in an argument called `student` (but within the `get_average`, function that still is a list, since the argument's name is irrelevant)

Then, in `get_average`, you try to access that **list** as `student['homework']`. Since the `student` argument is a list, that's why you get the error.

You might wanna do something like this?

```
def get_class_average(students):
    results=[];
    for student in students:
        results.append(get_average(student));
    return average(results)
```

**EDIT** (A per the OP's comment to this answer):

I guess good resources could be [this](http://sthurlow.com/python/lesson06/) and [this](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-en-pwmb1/0/1) (there's way more [Googling python lists dictionaries](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20lists%20dictionaries&oq=python%20lists%20dictionaries))

Comment: thnx for explaining it .. now i got my mistake..thnx for clearing it buddy.. can u plz tell me some resources where i can learn more about List and Dictionaries?

Comment: @Rudra, I added a couple of links. Have fun coding **:-)**

Comment: Yup..once again thanx for ur help

Comment: Good luck! And, since you haven't been a member of S.O. for too long, here it goes: Remember that if any of the answers solved your question, is a good practice that you mark it as accepted (big checkbox to the left of the answer). It'll give you reputation points, it'll give the person that spent time answering points and most importantly, it'll help future readers see that the answer was helpful. Please take a look to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 (not only for this post, but for your future questions as well) Cheers **:-)**

Answer (score 1):

`results.append(get_average(students))` should instead iterate over the list, since `get_average` expects a `dict`. Replace with:

```
for student in students:
  results.append(get_average(student))
```

Or simply:

```
def get_class_average(students):
    results = [get_average(student) for student in students]
    return average(results)
```

Comment: Ya now i got it..I applied the first one and it's working fine.. many thanx to u buddy.. but i am slightly confused about ur 2nd suggestion. "results = [get_average(student) for student in students]" how can we insert in a list without using .append() method.. can u plz explain..it'll be great for me to know this

Comment: @Rudra It's a language feature that allows for easier creation of lists, see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions.